# Prove/disprove: Let $G$ be abelian and $n\in\Bbb N$. Then $\{ g\in G:|g| \leq n\} $ forms a subgroup of $G$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group, and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove or disprove: $\left\{ g\in G:\left|g\right| \leq n\right\} $ forms a subgroup of $G$.

I'm pretty sure it's false, and the group of all roots of unity would be a counterexample, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Replace $\le$ with $\mid$, and then the statement would become true.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 3):

Consider $2,3 \in \mathbb{Z}_6$ (of orders $3$ and $2$ respectively). Then, $2+3=5$ has order $6$, which gives a counterexample for $G=\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $n=3$. Of course, this could be converted into an example inside the group of all roots of unity by considering $e^{2{\pi}i/3}=(e^{{2\pi}i/6})^2$ and $-1=(e^{{2\pi}i/6})^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $G=\Bbb Z_p\times \Bbb Z_q$ for coprime $p,q$ with $p<q$. (This is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_{pq}$.) We have $\lvert ([0]_p, [1]_q)\rvert=q$ and $\lvert ([1]_p, [0]_q)\rvert=p$; however, their sum, $([1]_p, [1]_q)$, has order $pq$. Here

$$[a]_m:=\{b\in\Bbb Z: m\mid a-b\}.$$

But then $\{x\in G: \lvert x\rvert\le q\}$ is not a subgroup of $G$ since it is not closed under $G$'s operation.